# How to find multiple maximum arguments in a scala list

Tags: scala

Good evening,
How to find multiple maximum arguments in a scala list:

```
val finale = list(2,2,3,4,6,6);    
val indexMax = finale.zipWithIndex.maxBy(_._1)._2
```

Here I can find only the argument of one maximum (6), but I want to find the two last (6) values

Comment: try `finale.groupBy(x => x).maxBy(_._1)`

Comment: Thanks " Luis Miguel Mejía Suárez " Very Helpful :)
I Solved My problem .

Comment: @LuisMiguelMejíaSuárez Would you mind posting it as an actual answer?

Comment: if you want to find last two 6 why you are ziping with index?

Comment: @AndreyTyukin Sorry for taking so long, I just deleted the comment to post it as an answer.

Answer (score 1):

Sightly modified from Rajkumar's comment, this snippet returns a List with the indexes of the maximum elements in a list.

```
def findMaximumIndices(list: List[Int]): List[Int] =
  list.zipWithIndex.groupBy(_._1).maxBy(_._1)._2.map(_._2)

val list = List(2,2,3,4,6,6)
val maximumIndices = findMaximumIndices(list)
// maximumIndices: List[Int] = List(4, 5)
```

It is quite obscure by the excessive use of tuple accessors with underscore anonymous functions notation. `(_._1).`

Answer (score 0):

How about a simple foldLeft?

```
  finale.foldLeft(Seq.empty[Int]) {
    case (max @ head :: _, element) if element == head => max :+ element
    case (max @ head :: _, element) if element > head => Seq(element)
    case (Nil, element) => Seq(element)
    case (max, _) => max
  }
```

This can be done even more efficient by not using Seq.

Comment: OP wants to "find" them - by which I assume the list of indices at whch the maximum values occur.